# How can a pyzmq SUB subscriber detect an offline PUB publisher?

Tags: python, zeromq, publish-subscribe, pyzmq

How can a **`SUB`**-scriber actually make sure, there is a **`PUB`**-lisher on the other side, otherwise not start at all?

**Details:**
 While everything works with my **`SUB`**-scriber code with a running remote **`PUB`**-lisher, when I `.connect()`+subscribe my client to a dummy server say a `localhost`, it doesn't notice that there are no **`PUB`**-lishers running, it just starts and waits.

I do it using standard procedure:

```
    sock = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    sock.connect("tcp://{}:{}".format(host, port))
    topic_filter = 'blah'
    sock.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topic_filter)
    # here should come something that warns about offline publisher...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sole PUB/SUB gives no means to create this

ZeroMQ is a powerful toolbox both conceptually and practically. One shall not try to "bend" library primitives --- that are on their own to be understood rather as just building blocks for more complex messaging and signalling purposes, than a real-life solutions --- so as to do things that were not principally covered in the initial **S**caleable **F**ormal **C**ommunication **P**attern design archetype.

**`PUB/SUB`** archetype does **just** `PUB/SUB`.

**`PUB`**-broadcasts to all, if any, `SUB`s present at the very moment and each, if any, **`SUB`** listens to what has arrived ( and if anything did arrive, it applies filter ... yes, filtering on `SUB`-side loads network ).

---

### Still - one may design a multi-archetype approach to solve this.

Let me sketch a basic scheme for the most straightforward one.

Assuming you are in a full control of the both sides ( design-wise and implementation-wise ).

```
# /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
#
# [Side A]
#        |_____aKnockSOCK = context.socket( zmq.PAIR )
#        |     + .setsockopt( zmq.CONFLATE )
#        |     + .bind()
#        |
#        |_____anEmitSOCK = context.socket( zmq.PUB )
#              + .bind()
#
isNotReceivedSigEXIT  = False
while( isNotReceviedSigEXIT ):
       if ( 0 == aKnockSOCK.poll( aFastPollIN, zmq.POLLIN ) ):
           # nobody new knocking to setup ...
           # ------------------------------------------------
           # do the main job,
           #    with countdown segmentation
           #    to escape to the outer loop
           #    so as to check for new SUB-s
           #    knocking as they come to the show
           # ------------------------------------------------
       else:
           aKnockSOCK.send( "aKnockSOCK ACK: service is ready. Go .connect()" )
#
# --------------------------------------------------------
# ZeroMQ resources graceful termination 
#        socket closes + context dismantle & clean exit



# /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
#
#[Side B]
#        |_____aKnockSOCK = context.socket( zmq.PAIR )
#        |     + .setsockopt( zmq.CONFLATE )
#        |
#        |_____aRecvrSOCK = context.socket( zmq.SUB )
#
#
isToBreakEXIT = False
for nthAttempt in range( 10 ):
    if ( isToBreakEXIT ):
         break
    try:
          aKnockSOCK.connect( ... )
    except:
          ReportConnectERROR( ... )
          sleep( ... )
          continue
    # ---------------------------------- once local aKnockSOCK got instantiated
    for kthPoll in range( 10 ):
        if ( 0 == aKnockSOCK.poll( aLongPollIN, zmq.POLLIN ) ):
           sleep( thisCouldBeAddedToLongPollIN )
        else:
           # ----------------------------------------- .recv() + dismantle
           aKnockSOCK.recv()
           aKnockSOCK.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 )
           aKnockSOCK.close()
           # ----------------------------------------- .connect() + use
           aRecvrSOCK.connect( ... )
           aRecvrSOCK.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, ... )
           # ----------------------------------------- [Side B] main job start
           # ----------------------------------------- [Side B] main job end
           isToBreakEXIT = True
           break
    pass
# --------------------------------------------------------
# ZeroMQ resources graceful termination 
#        socket closes + context dismantle & clean exit
```